# http client in proxygen?

Tags: c++, httpclient, build-error

hi i am using proxygen by facebook to create a simple hhtpclient . i am trying to run  their default httpclient example. I am using the following command to build it:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -o my_echo   CurlClient.o CurlClientMain.o -lproxygenhttpserver -lfolly -lglog -lgflags -pthread
```

but i am getting the following error:

```
CurlClient.o: In function `CurlService::CurlClient::connectSuccess(proxygen::HTTPUpstreamSession*)':
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClient.cpp:69: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPUpstreamSession::newTransaction(proxygen::HTTPTransactionHandler*)'
CurlClientMain.o: In function `main':
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClientMain.cpp:91: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::HTTPConnector(proxygen::HTTPConnector::Callback*, folly::HHWheelTimer*)'
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClientMain.cpp:102: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::connect(folly::EventBase*, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::map<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey, int, std::less<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey const, int> > > const&, folly::SocketAddress const&)'
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClientMain.cpp:91: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::~HTTPConnector()'
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClientMain.cpp:99: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::connectSSL(folly::EventBase*, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::shared_ptr<folly::SSLContext> const&, ssl_session_st*, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::map<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey, int, std::less<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey const, int> > > const&, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::string const&)'
/home/kshitij/proxygen/httpclient/samples/curl/CurlClientMain.cpp:91: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::~HTTPConnector()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what could be the possible error. correct me if i am building it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g++ -std=c++11 -o my_echo   CurlClient.o CurlClientMain.o HttpUpstreamSession.o -lproxygenhttpserver -lfolly -lglog -lgflags -pthread

The HttpUpstreamSession.h include is referenced but the implementation is defined in its .cpp in the same directory. You need to either build the .cpp or use the .o file in your build.

Answer (score 0):

What I used to compile that example:

`gcc -I/usr/local/include -o a.out CurlClientMain.cpp CurlClient.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lglog -lgflags -lstdc++ -lfolly -lproxygenlib -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -lz -lwangle`

Note the inclusion of **libproxygenlib**.